# Django project with independent apps or project linking to multiple django projects?

Tags: python, django

i´m quite new to django. My question is probably very simple but i´m struggling on what is the best approach. I am trying to develop a web platform for work. It is supposed to have a homepage that shows four different services. By clicking in one of those services a login page should be displayed entering what i think it should be a different project because it is going to have their own views, users and database. The question is how do i build a homepage like this? What is the best approach? If having four django projects in a homepage is the way how do i do that?